# In a WordPress plugin, how do you output HTML code inside the DOM header?

Tags: functions, headers

HTML:

```
<header>
   <!-- I want to add html code here -->
</header>
```

Function:

```
 function add_html_to_header {
   <b> Hello World </b>
 }
 add_action('','add_html_to_header')
```

Expected Html results:

```
<header id="header">
    <b> Hello World </b>
</header>
```

**EDIT:** Is it possible without using `Javascript`?

Comment: First of all, enable PHP's `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `WP_DEBUG`. You'll see your syntax is seriously bad.

Comment: Why do you need to add it using a function, rather than putting the html straight into the page (or header etc) template?

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772510/wordpress-filter-to-modify-final-html-output

Comment: Related to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6UNSafWC9a8

Comment: It's quite difficult! Obviously the problem lies that you're trying to insert - -- right in the middle --- of the header.php template file. Could we filter that file somehow? Mayber, conditionally override the file, and string replace the </head> tag somehow?

Comment: Max Yudin, you're comments and actions are ... seriously bad. Unhold this question please, and remove your negative comment about a user.

Comment: related to: https://www.ibenic.com/include-or-override-wordpress-templates/

Comment: @Monkey Puzzle so the code can work in a plugin. It's specifically hard to put in a plugin.

Comment: related to: https://wordpress.org/plugins/header-footer/

Answer (score 4):

You can add html to the site head using this function:

```
// Add scripts to wp_head()
function add_head_html() { ?>
    <!-- html goes here -->
    <?php }
    add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_head_html' );
```

But if you're talking about the html element `<header>` (as it sounds like from your edits) it sounds like overcomplicating things, but you might want to look at injecting it with jquery into the right spot using a solution such as this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9866637/3387817

Answer (score 2):

You can use action hooks:

```
<header>
   <!-- I want to add html code here -->
   <?php do_action('wpse_myheader'); ?>
</header>
```

Then you can use:

```
function add_html_to_header { ?>
   <b> Hello World </b>
<?php }
 add_action('wpse_myheader','add_html_to_header');
```

Comment: Is it possible to use a function only without accessing the `<header>` html?

Comment: That way, you have to do the DOM manipulation using JS